# d3 bar chart scale reversed on y-axis, doesn't look like the classic problem, why is it acting odd?

Tags: d3.js, scale, axis

Drawing a histogram in d3 (vertical bar chart), works fine except the y-axis scale is reversed. Here is the code that (almost) works:

```
let maxFrequency = d3.max(histData, d=> d.length); 
let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0,config.height - config.margin.top - config.margin.bottom])
    .domain([0,maxFrequency]);  //<-- this is wrong, right? It should be [maxFrequency,0]

let xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, (config.width - config.margin.left - config.margin.right)])
    .domain(histData.map(d => d.Name))
    .padding(0.2);
//Draw the histogram bars
let bars = config.svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(histData);
bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d)=> yScale(d.length))
    .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.Name) + config.margin.left)
    .attr("y", (d)=> config.height - config.margin.bottom - yScale(d.length))
    .attr("fill", "red");//"#2a5599");
let axisX = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
config.svgContainer.append("g")
    .style("transform", `translate(${config.margin.left}px,${config.height - 
config.margin.bottom}px)`)
    .call(axisX)
let axisY = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
config.svgContainer.append("g")
    .style('transform',`translate(${config.margin.left}px,${config.margin.top}px)`)
    .call(axisY);
```

This code produces this graph.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBlrC.png)

Normally you need to reverse the order of the domain attribute for the y-axis. Here is the graph when I use the ".domain([maxFrequency,0])" code with no other changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq3YT.png)

You can see that the y-axis now is correct but the bars look wonky. On closer inspection you can see that the data (1,9,40,80) is still being represented, but the bars are a now reversed. The bars are now height 79 (80-1), 71 (80-9), 40 (80-40), and 0 (80-80).

I hope this is something simple I'm not seeing. I can't find any posted solutions for something that sounds like this.

Comment: Reverse the range: `.range([config.height - config.margin.top - config.margin.bottom, 0])`.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I tried that. Actually I tried all four combinations just to be sure. The result was when the zeros are both at the start or the end, I get the wrong scale, proper bars (figure 1 in my original post), otherwise it's the second figure.